# I need to display activity by day by hours with php and mysql. below is my failing code

Tags: php, mysql, html

using this two query. the second one inside a while loop, i am able to display on a table das as rows and hours as columns to get the count of activity by month by day by hour. the problem here is that the is not showing the activity per hour in order by hour, which should be in the second query. please check my querys and if you have any questions let me know. The script is displaying de information but not in order by hours ( 0 to 23 ).

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT month(timestamp), day(timestamp) AS days
          FROM security_transactions
     where timestamp <= getdate()
     order by month(timestamp), day(timestamp)";
     $result = odbc_exec($conn,$query);

$number_day = odbc_result($result,'days');
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) as hours
          FROM security_transactions 
      WHERE MONTH(timestamp) = $month_count 
      AND DAY(timestamp) = $$number_day
      GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, timestamp)";
```

the idea is to have a lines like this:

day          | 1   | 2  | 3 | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7 | 8 | 9  |  10| 12 and so on...

january, 1   | 452 | 458| 53| 584| 125| 056| 57| 48| 589| 410| and so on...

Comment: Is `$$number_day` a typo? That may be your issue. Is `$month_count` defined somewhere?

Comment: Nice catch there, I just fixed it but is still not giving me the activity per houers in order

Comment: I need to have the result for each day activity from hour 0 to hour 23.

Comment: use backticks (``) around your `timestamp` column too

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for you to do 2 seperate queries.  I'd do a query like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as countof, year(timestamp) as years, month(timestamp) as months, day(timestamp) as days, hour(timestamp) as hours
FROM security_transactions
WHERE timestamp <= getdate()
GROUP BY years, months, days, hours
```

You get one row for each combination, so your frontend code, simply needs to detect when the year/month/day combination changes, which can be done in a simple loop.

Ok, for some help with the php loop (not tested)

```
$sql = '...query';

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $daykey = $row['years'].'-'.$row['months'].'-'.$row['days'];
  if (!array_key_exists($daykey, $data)) {
     //prefill the hours
     $data[$daykey] = array_fill(0, 23, 0);
  }
  $data[$daykey][$row['hours'] = $row['countof'];
}
// Now you have array already setup with day/hours counts.  Also solves issue if hours don't have counts.
foreach ($data as $day => $hours) {
  //Output your day markup here
  foreach ($hours as $hour => $val) {
   // Output one hour value
   echo "$val |";
  }
  // close your day markup here (newline or whatever you're using)
}
```

Comment: That is amazin thanks a lot. i'll ask you somethin else, it will sound bad, but i wil need some help bulding my new php while loop for this one. it is so much different than what i had in mind.